# Problems understanding Django app dependencies

Tags: python, django

I'm relatively new to Django working on my first project.

Im getting kinda confused when it comes to app dependencies in Django. Comming from **Odoo** *(Python-based ERP-System)* Apps/Modules all have their own `manifest.py` which handles dependencies amongst other things.

So you can say **App1** depends on **App2** and cannot be installed without its dependency being installed.

How would I handle something like that in Django? Say I have an app called `account` for user accounts and I wanna make a new app `account_profile` where I put everything related to user profiles.

Classes in `account_profile` may inherit from `account`.

What are the best practices to achieve something similar in Django? Or is it even needed here?

Comment: It's more a matter of preference whether you put things in different apps or not. In general, think of a Django app as something that is useful standalone and you'd want to re-use in the future in another project. Your main project app would then use functionalities from these various apps (in the same way you use 3rd party apps). Should account and account_profile be two separate apps? If they are both very specific to your project, then why separate them? It really depends on your particular use case.

Comment: A good example where you might create different apps is an e-commerce website: accounts, the products you sell, the blog and the payment/shipping module could be separate apps, so if you one day build another website, you can re-use the blog, or the accounts, or the payment/shipping part...